# RSelenium: Select option from dropdown

Tags: r, rselenium

I use RSelenium to fill in a webform. To select an option from a dropdown I use the following:

```
xpathoption <- paste0("//select[@id = '",samplepatient[p,'name'],"']/option[",samplepatient[p,'value'],"]")

optionelem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", xpathoption)
selectelem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath"
                   , paste0("//select[@id = '",samplepatient[p,'name'],"']"))
optionelem$clickElement()
selectelem$screenshot(display = T)
```

I use the following to check if the correct option was selected:

```
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", paste0("//select[@id = '",samplepatient[p,'name'],"']"))$getElementAttribute("value")[[1]]
```

The problem I have is when the `clickElement()` command is run twice, the result of the last command changes. I also checked the outcome with `screenshot()`. It also shows that a different option is switched to when using the `clickElement()` command twice.

Is there a different way to select the option from a dropdown list, that is not creating this behavior?

I use a docker on ubuntu with firefox 3.0.1.

The form is from a calculator I want to use. To open the form itself you need to first check the disclaimer, like so:

```
remDrv$navigate('http://riskcalculator.facs.org/RiskCalculator/')

remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id = 'chkDisclaimer']")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1) 
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id = 'btnContinue']")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
```

a reproducable example after the disclaimer is:

```
#select age group
optionelem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//select[@id = 'AgeGroup']/option[3]")
selectelem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//select[@id = 'AgeGroup']")
#first attempt
optionelem$clickElement()
selectelem$getElementAttribute("value")
# result = 3
#second attempt
optionelem$clickElement()
selectelem$getElementAttribute("value")
# result = 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to give the webpage you are filling the form on?

Comment: I added the webpage info in the question

Comment: I have looked into this running the most recent chrome and I don't see this issue (that is result is returned as 3 in both cases). I will run Docker image standalone-firefox-debug:3.0.1-barium shortly and see if the issue is present.

Comment: I can reproduce this running `docker run -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4444:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:3.0.1-barium` . It is likely an issue with geckodriver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/322

Comment: So I can better switch to the most recent chrome version to run this?

Comment: Running `docker run -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.0.1-barium` I dont experience this issue. If chrome is useful for you then maybe use this image. Otherwise you could try an older version of the firefox image see https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-firefox-debug/tags/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, the issue has not to do with RSelenium but with the docker used. I now use a chrome docker (standalone-chrome) that does not have the same issue with selecting an option in a dropdown.

Comment: Just to note that a previous version of firefox may not exhibit this issue and it would most likely be fixed in a future firefox version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't come across any issues when selecting options using `clickElement`
for example:

```
remDrv$navigate('http://riskcalculator.facs.org/RiskCalculator/')
remDrv$findElement("id", "chkDisclaimer")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1) 
remDrv$findElement("id", "btnContinue")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
#select age group
ageElems <- remDrv$findElements("css", "#AgeGroup option")
ageElems[[3]]$clickElement()
#select Diabetes
diaElems <- remDrv$findElements("css", "#Diabetes option")
diaElems[[2]]$clickElement()
# Select Gender
genderElems <- remDrv$findElements("css", "#Gender option")
genderElems[[1]]$clickElement()
```

When running in Docker you can use "debug" image and a VNC viewer to see exactly whats happening in the browser.

Comment: I edited the question to give you a reproducible example. You point out that it works first time around. The issue is that it does not give a reliable result when selecting an option more than one time (it switches back and forth from option 3 to 1 in AgeGroup for example.